# Can I obtain real user ip with "iptables": false enabled?

Tags: docker, iptables, docker-swarm, real-ip

I user `"iptables": false` option in docker daemon config:

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json:
{
  "iptables": false
}
```

I run service with options `--publish mode=host`, `--mode=global` similar to [this approach](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25526#issuecomment-275292393).

But when I get `X-Real-IP` header in my application its value is `172.18.0.1` but not real user ip.

When I start Docker daemon without `"iptables": false` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` all works fine and I get real user ip.

But I need to set `"iptables": false` to preserve iptables changes with Docker.

**Is it possible to get real user ip with `"iptables": false` in Docker daemon configuration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the rules that Docker creates without `"iptables": true` and replicate them with `"iptables": false` (which is the default).

These rules in particular are needed to masquerade the IP:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE`

`iptables -t nat -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE`